# Can someone help me to understand the following code?

Tags: javascript

```
function talksAbout(node, string) { 
    if (node.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) { 
            if (talksAbout(node.childNodes[i], string))
                return true;
        } 
        return false; 
    } else if (node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE) { 
        return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1;
    } 
} 
console.log(talksAbout(document.body, "book"));
```

This code i found in Eloquent Javascript on page no. 234. It would be so helpful if someone explain it line by line.

Comment: It checks if the document contains the word "book".

Comment: i know this but can not understand the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function talksAbout(node, string) { // declares a function called talksAbout, which takes two parameters: node and string
    if (node.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE) { // checks if the passed in node is an "ELEMENT_NODE" - <body><div><span>etc
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) { // loops through all the child nodes of the passed in node
            if (talksAbout(node.childNodes[i], string)) // recursively calls the function on each node
                return true; // returns true if the function returns true
        } // ends the for loop block
        return false; // returns false
    } else if (node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE) { // if the node is a TEXT node
        return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1; // returns true if the passed in string is somewhere in this text node
    } // ends ths else if block
} // ends the function block
console.log(talksAbout(document.body, "book")); // execute the function, passing in the body element, and a string "book", logging the result to the console
```

basically, this function looks to see if the word "book" exists in TEXT on the page - so `<div class="book">` will NOT be considered as a match

Answer (score 1):

DOM is made of nodes of different types. Body, Div etc are element nodes while input:text, text Area are text nodes and so on. Function talksAbout recursively loops through the childNodes of given 'body' element node until it finds a text node with value "book".

Answer (score 0):

this code search word "book" in your page and return true if found. I think the code is very simple to understand and read.But you need to know this to understand (in bottom of page)

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp